# Linq: pass GroupBy result to a function

Tags: c#, linq

I need to group items in a list and then pass each group to a function for further elaboration.
This is my code:

```
var list = new List<MyObj>(); // list is created ad populated elsewhere in code...

var query = list.AsEnumerable();

query = query.Where(x => x.MyProp == true).Select(x => x); // query definition is way more complicated

var grp = query.GroupBy(x => new { x.Name, x.Surname }).ToList();
```

Here `grp` is of type `List<IGrouping<'a, MyObj>>`.

I can easily iterate through my items with:

```
foreach (var g in grp)
{
    foreach (var o in g)
    {
        // here "o" is of type MyObj
    }
}
```

but I don't know how to create a function that receives a group and iterates through its items:

```
foreach (var g in grp)
{
    DoSomethingWithGroup(g);
}
```

This is because I have an anonymous type (Key) in grp definition.

I tried to replace the Key anonymous type with a custom type:

```
private class GrpKey
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}

/* ... */

var grp = query.GroupBy(x => new GrpKey { Name = x.Name, Surname = x.Surname }).ToList();
```

This way grp is of type `List<IGrouping<MyGrpKey, MyObj>>` instead of `List<IGrouping<'a, MyObj>>`.

I could then create a function:

```
private void DoSomethingWithGroup(IGrouping<MyGrpKey, MyObj>) { /* ... */ }
```

Unfortunately, this way grouping doesn't work anymore: grp now contains as many groups as items in the source list, each one with a single item.

Comment: Is it not `List<IGrouping<TKey, IEnumerable<TGrouped>>>`?  You'll probably want to define a concrete type as the key though (or perhaps use a `ValueTuple`).

Comment: As per what I understood from your problem is group contains as many groups as items in the source list, each one with a single item. Because You are not grouping it by any common attribute. Name and Surname for each record will work as Key so it will definitely give single item for each source list.

Comment: `var query = list.AsEnumerable();` <-- This is entirely unnecessary btw.

Comment: Assuming you're not using Entity Framework (which still _requires_ Anonymous Types in Linq expressions and EF Core 6 still doesn't support `record` types, bah!) you should be able to use a C# `ValueTuple` - and this will also be slightly more efficient too because anonymous-types are always GC-allocated but `ValueTuples` have less overhead.

Comment: "Unfortunately, this way grouping doesn't work anymore: grp now contains as many groups as items in the source list, each one with a single item." - yes, this is because `GroupBy` will use the default equality of the `TKey` type, but your `class GrpKey` does not `override Equals` nor does it implement `IEquatable<GrpKey>`.

Comment: `var grp = query.GroupBy(x => (Name : x.Name, Surname : x.Surname )).ToList();`

Comment: Does `DoSomethingWithGroup` actually need to access each group's `Key` value (i.e. `Name` and `Surname`), or does it only want to get at the `MyObj` objects? If so, then you can still use anonymous-types, but upcast the `IGrouping<TKey,T>` to `IEnumerable<T>` which _erases_ `TKey`, so no-more anonymous types are exposed, allowing you to pass the list-of-groups into and out of methods.

Comment: Wow! So many comments and hints!
@Dai: Thank you for pointing out that I should override ``Equals`` or implement ``IEquatable<GrpKey>`` if I want to use a custom key class. ``AsEnumerable`` is actually needed in my code, otherwise C# complains that it cannot convert from ``System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MyObj>`` to ``System.Collections.Generic.List<MyObj>`` in line where I use ``Where`` method.
The upcasting approach is also very intresting. I think I'll use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of specifying your method like you did:

```
private void DoSomethingWithGroup(IGrouping<MyGrpKey, MyObj>)
```

separate the key and the elements into their on parameters

```
private void DoSomethingWithGroup<T>(T groupKey, IEnumerable<MyObj> entities)
```

With this change you can do the following:

```
//Populate list with some dummy data
var list = new List<MyObj>()
{
    new MyObj { Id = 1, MyProp = true, Name = "A", Surname = "B"},
    new MyObj { Id = 2, MyProp = false, Name = "A", Surname = "B"},
    new MyObj { Id = 3, MyProp = true, Name = "B", Surname = "B"},
    new MyObj { Id = 4, MyProp = true, Name = "B", Surname = "B"},
    new MyObj { Id = 5, MyProp = true, Name = "C", Surname = "B"},
}; 

//Perform the grouping
var groups = list
   .Where(x => x.MyProp)
   .GroupBy(x => new { x.Name, x.Surname })
   .ToList();

//Perform some arbitrary action on the group basis
foreach (var group in groups)
{
    DoSomethingWithGroup(group.Key, group);
}
```

---

If the implementation of the `DoSomethignWithGroup` looks like this:

```
void DoSomethingWithGroup<T>(T groupKey, IEnumerable<MyObj> entities)
{
    Console.WriteLine(groupKey);
    foreach (var entity in entities)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"- {entity.Id}");
    }
}
```

then the output will be this:

```
{ Name = A, Surname = B }
- 1
{ Name = B, Surname = B }
- 3
- 4
{ Name = C, Surname = B }
- 5
```

[DotnetFiddle link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eMkhu8)

Answer (score 0):

If the key is not needed in your function, you can omit that in the method. A `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` is an `IEnumerable<TElement>` so you could just define it as:

```cs
private void DoSomethingWithGroup(IEnumerable<MyObj> items)
{
   ///...
}
```